# Using a custom LWRP in Chef

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, chef-recipe

I'm trying to write a custom LWRP for deploying flask applications.

I've referenced the following cookbook extensively :

https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/application_python

I have the following in my recipe

```
application "packaginator" do
  path "/my/apps/packaginator"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  repository "https://github.com/coderanger/packaginator.git"
  revision "master"
  migrate false
  packages ["libpq-dev", "git-core","python-pip"]

  flask do
    packages ["boto"]
  end
end
```

Inside of my cookbooks recipe folder I have a file named flask.rb that contains the resource definition.

Likewise in my cookbooks provider folder I have a file named flask.rb that is the provider.

Whenever I try to apply the recipe on my vagrant box I receive the following :

FATAL: NameError: No resource found for flask. Tried application_flask, flask

This is my first custom LWRP so what simple steps am I missing so that I can use my custom lwrp?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flask.rb should be not in **recipe** folder, but in **resource** folder. Then you can reference it in your recipe as **application_flask**.